# How to addsubview to a view on class1 from class2?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I'm trying to do a really simple thing - I've got a main Xib file for the whole app and another Xib file for a small view.

I want the small view (Xib called "additionalView.xib") to appear in the first Xib ("ViewController.xib").

I have succeeded to do so in the "ViewController.m" but I want more - I want to do it from "additionalView.m"

There is a method I created called "openView:" in "additionalView.m" and it looks like this:

---

```
-(IBAction)openView:(id)sender

{

  ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

  NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"additionalView" owner:self options:nil];    

  UIView *nibView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];

  [vc.view addSubview:nibView];

}
```

---

The method is being called and the lines are being read by the debugger - but nothing happens.
No crash - No error - No small view in bigger view.

Why is that?

I know that the last line is probably what's 
screwing everything up but i don't know how to put it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    [self.view addView:view.vc];
```

However, I'm not sure what is you view structure here. You say your -(IBAction)openView:(id)sender is in your "additionalView.m", but it is not the main view controller, correct? You need to do this in the main controller, so basically move the openView: method to your ViewController.m

And you normally need a separate view controller for each view to keep things neat and separate, so the additionalView.m should be an instance of UIViewController, which you can then create from your main view as follows:

```
-(IBAction)openView:(id)sender

 {

 AdditionalView *vc = [[AdditionalView alloc] initWithNibName:@"additionalView"];


 [self.view vc.view];

 }
```

Comment: You are correct. But the issue is that i've got tons of lines in the ViewController.m and i was hoping to organize things a bit by using different classes (such as "additionalView.m"). This is why i wanted to know how to refer to the ViewController.xib from another class.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];` creates a **new** view controller.  Because it's new, it's not the one that already exists in the view controller hierarchy that's managing the display.

Your method needs to access the existing view controller.  How it does that depends on your app's structure and which object has a reference to the original controller object.

Answer (score 1):

You have options ... First you don't need to create a view controller vc if you just need the view . Create a uiview and add it . 
Option 1: pass a ref to the app vc as suggested above and then : 
[appVC.view addsubview:additionalView]

This will add it to main.

Use a view controller manager / ref in the app delegate that you can refer to as delegate and add your view to the current showing view.

Hope this helps